# Postgresql C How to convert uint64_t into numeric?

Tags: c, postgresql, uint64

Postgres doesn't support uint64_t , the largest integer type is BIGINT which's range is equal to int64. I need to return an unit64_t var from C function, how can I convert it into numeric then I can return a numeric from my function?

Comment: Will Postgres be storing numbers that could exceed a 63 bit int?

Comment: In C, you could cast from uint64_t to int64_t and vica versa. I do not figure out your problem.

Comment: The only issue would be if it used the 64th bit because then the number would become a negative number and OP would have to use something like ```__uint128_t``` from ```stdint.h``` instead of ```uint64_t```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find an existing function which handles this conversion directly. Worse than that, all of the structures and functions used to build `NUMERIC` values appear to be local to [`numeric.c`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c), and there's not much of any use in the accompanying [header](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/utils/numeric.h), so I'm not sure how you're expected to build them yourself (looks like we are [not the first to notice this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12612600)).

Seems that this basically limits you to the type's SQL-level API (i.e. the built-in type casts and arithmetic operations). I think the only other SQL type which is both castable to `NUMERIC`, and wide enough to hold a `uint64`, is `TEXT`. In other words, the simplest approach might be to convert your value to a string, and pass it into the `NUMERIC` parsing routine, e.g.:

```
char uint64_string [21];
sprintf(uint64_string, "%" PRIu64, uint64_val);
PG_RETURN_DATUM(DirectFunctionCall3(numeric_in, CStringGetDatum(uint64_string), 0, -1));
```

Answer (score 2):

C's `uint64_t` and `int64_t` are castable to each other without loss of information (in twos-complement arithmetic, but I doubt you're using a UNIVAC), so you *could* cast all `uint64_t` quantities to `int64_t` before writing them to the database and back to `uint64_t` on read.

There are some potential problems, though.  First off, *do not* do this if you ever need to store actual negative numbers in the relevant database columns, because you won't be able to tell whether they were negative numbers or numbers above 2<sup>63</sup>−1 when you read them back.  Also, all SQL operations will treat all numbers greater than 2<sup>63</sup>−1 as negative.  This may or may not be a problem, depending on what you are using these large numbers for and how complicated the queries involving them tend to be.

EDIT: I just realized that by "numeric" you probably meant PostgreSQL's arbitrary-precision NUMERIC column type.  Unfortunately I am not having any luck whatsoever finding documentation for how to work with this type below the level of textual SQL.  The only thing I can suggest is for you to read the header files for writing server-side extensions in C and/or ask for help on the pg mailing lists.